# How do I add text to a non-editable text view

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nstextview

I have a NSTextView in my XIB UI. I made the @property and everything, and I wrote the code

```
[self.output setEditable:NO];
```

I only want it to be user non-editable, but I want to be able to add text to it using

```
[self.output insertText:@"some text"];
```

Is there a non-user editable function or any way to do this? (I'm probably missing something.)

Comment: Your question already has an answer [here](http://www.cocoabuilder.com/archive/cocoa/67870-inserttext-on-non-editable-nstextview.html#55524).

Comment: @DanielLe I still don't fully understand. Which method do I use?

Comment: You should grab the NSTextView's textStorage: `textView.textStorage`. It's an object of type [NSTextStorage](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSTextStorage_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSTextStorage/setWords:). Then you can modify it using the [replaceCharactersInRange:withString: method](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableAttributedString_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSMutableAttributedString/replaceCharactersInRange:withString:) of the superclass.

Comment: [self.output setStringValue:     ]; //?

Comment: Why have you accepted an answer which results in an exception  ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should grab and modify the NSTextView's textStorage: `output.textStorage`. It's an object of type NSTextStorage. Then you can modify it using the [replaceCharactersInRange:withString: method](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableAttributedString_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSMutableAttributedString/replaceCharactersInRange:withString:) of the superclass.

```
[self.output.textStorage replaceCharactersInRange:NSMakeRange(self.output.string.length, 0) withString:@" Hello, world!"];
```

A more straightforward approach is:

```
[self.output setString:[self.output.string stringByAppendingString:@" Hello, world!"]];
```

Comment: Just asking, but will this replace all the text in my textview or just add text to it?

Comment: It depends on the range that you pass in. In my example above, the beginning of `" Hello, world!"` will be at the end of the current string. I'd suggest you try it out and read the manual for more information. Good luck!

Comment: Also, it throws error no method text found. It's late. Sorry for all these questions.

Comment: No problem, it's noon for me. I suspect you're not connecting the IBOutlet for the NSTextView to the correct view. Please see http://youtu.be/xq-a7e_l_4I?t=2m14s and reconnect your IBOutlet.

Comment: nope, this is the problem  :  NSMakeRange(self.output.text ..... )     NSTextView has no property or method called 'text' .  You want self.output.stringValue     . which btw also has a setter. (inherited from NSControl)

Comment: @XtremeHek3r is using a NSTextView, not a NSTextField.

Comment: try self.output.textStorage.string ;)

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
[self.output setStringValue: @"some string" ];
```

setStringValue:  is inherited from NSControl, along with setIntegerValue: setDoubleValue:  etc, etc..

Comment: @XtremeHek3r is using a NSTextView, not a NSTextField.